# How To Rotate Variables Evenly Except If They Are Blank

Tags: php, hyperlink, rotation

I know how to code a rotater but how can i make one that skip pass empty $stuff_link variable?

I have 4 links variable as shown below but sometimes they are blank. So what I need to do is use a rotater to rotate between the 4 variables but if for say $stuff_link is blank skip pass it.

```
$stuff_link
$stuff_link2 
$stuff_link3
$stuff_link4
```

The code below is where i will put it inside of.

```
if(percentChance(35) && $stuff_status == 1)
{

    rotator goes here       
}
```

This below is function for percentChance

```
function percentChance($chance){
// Notice we go from 0-99 - therefore a 100% $chance is always larger
$randPercent = mt_rand(0,99);
 return $chance > $randPercent;
}
```

Comment: Storing your "stuff" in an array would go a long way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made things a bit interesting using 4 variables and having one without a number on the end. If you must use those as is something like this would do the job:

```php
$stuffs = array('', '2', '3', '4'); // Array of possible variable endings
$random = array_rand($stuffs); // Pick one
$selected = $stuffs[$random]; // Get the ending

// Check if the variable is empty, if not pick another
while (empty(${'stuff_link'.$selected})) {
    $random = array_rand($stuffs);
    $selected = $stuffs[$random];
}

// Output
echo ${'stuff_link'.$selected};
```

If you can move your variables into an array, then life becomes easier:

```
// Example array
$stuff_link = array();
$stuff_link[] = 'stuff 1';
$stuff_link[]  = '';
$stuff_link[] = 'stuff 3';
$stuff_link[] = 'stuff 4';

shuffle($stuff_link); // mix them up

// Keep shuffling until the first value is not empty
while (empty($stuff_link[0])) {
    shuffle($stuff_link);
}

// Output
echo $stuff_link[0];
```

Comment: well each of the $stuff_link is populated from information from my DB.  Also they need to be shown an even amount of time.

Comment: As in show each non-blank link on the same page in a random order?

Comment: Im using this to split test aff links so i need it to rotate each evenly this i tested it shows the same thing multiple time b4 switching sometimes

Comment: To _guarantee_ each link is shown equally you'll have to store how often each link has been shown on the server or the last one to be shown (either in the DB or in a flat file). The alternative is using rand() or shuffle() and assuming that, over a long enough time period, each will be shown equally.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand from the question, you'll need a function similar to this:

```
function isEmpty($link) {
    return ($link == NULL || $link == "");            
}

if (!isEmpty($stuff_link))
{
    // Only enters if not empty
}
```

Comment: thanks well i didnt know about isEmpty also what i want is to rotate between the 4 variables but if 1 isEmpty skip it